# call multiple api urls and call at same time

Tags: javascript, json, rest, api

I have three API urls, each have the same object names, I wish to call all apis at the same time.

My js so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var first = 'https:first';
    var second = 'https://second';
    var third = 'https://third';

    $('#get-data').click(function() {
        var showData = $('#show-data');
        $.getJSON(first,second,third function(data) {
            showData.empty();
            var items = data.map(function(elem) {
                return $("<li />", {
                text: elem.title
            });
        });

        var list = $('<ul />').append(items);
            showData.append(list);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Look at `Promise.all`!

Comment: thank you ill look into this

Comment: No problem. I your case will be something like: `Promise.all([ $.getJSON(first),  $.getJSON(second),  $.getJSON(third)]).then(function(values){ //do something })`

Comment: nice, ill try this thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API calls are asynchronous, and they execute in the sequence you write them inside your code. execution doesn't really matter because the 'then' could be called in different order as it was executed.

If you want to do anything on the execution of all three services i would recommend using **[async.js](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)**. look at the following example:

```
links = ['http://first','http://second','http://third']
data = [];

$('#get-data').click(function() {
    // ...
    async.each(links, function(link,callback){
        $.getJSON(link, function(res){
            data.push(res);
            callback();
        })
    }, function(err){
        if(!err){
            // your code goes here
            // data[0] contains data from link 1
            // data[1] contains data from link 1
            // data[2] contains data from link 2
        }
    })
    // ...
});
```